# Create sticks sound in mp3 or midi file - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, audio, mp3, midi-instrument

I have a project in NodeJs which I am building a music in a midi file, using MidiWriter library. This library has a set of instrument but I want to generate the baqueta sound.

I want to play this sticks sound to indicate the compass of the melody.

I try to download a mp3 file with this sound and put together, spliced with a delay, but I don't have good results.

Someone know a library in node to play this kind of sound?

Thanks! :)